# Trying to replace text in a table in a .docx file based on a regex

Tags: python, regex, module, docx

I am trying to replace a text in a table in a *.docx* file in Python. I am fairly new with Python, so here's the code that I will explain later on:

```
from typing import List, Any
from docx import Document
import re
import sys


label_name = sys.argv[1:][0]

file_name = "MyDocFile.docx"
doc = Document(file_name)
cell_text_array = []
target_index = 0


def index_cells(doc_obj):
    global cell_text_array
    for table in doc_obj.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                cell_text_array.append(cell.text)


def docx_replace_regex(doc_obj, regex, replace):
    global cell_text_array
    for p in doc_obj.paragraphs:
        if regex.search(p.text):
            inline = p.runs
            # Loop added to work with runs (strings with same style)
            for i in range(len(inline)):
                if regex.search(inline[i].text):
                    text = regex.sub(replace, inline[i].text)
                    inline[i].text = text

    for table in doc_obj.tables:
        for row in table.rows:
            for cell in row.cells:
                docx_replace_regex(cell, regex, replace)


# index the cells in the document
index_cells(doc)


# everything after: /myregex/
target_index = cell_text_array.index('myregex')

# the text that I actually need is 3 spots after 'myregex'
target_index += 3 

former_label = cell_text_array[target_index]

# find regex and replace
regex1 = re.compile(re.escape(r"" + former_label))
replace1 = r"" + label_name
print(regex1)
print(replace1)

# call the replace function and save what has been replaced

docx_replace_regex(doc, regex1, replace1)
doc.save('result1.docx')
```

The first function `index_cells()` basically opens *MyDocFile.docx* and searches every string from the tables the *.docx* file has and saves them in `cell_text_array`. I have taken the next function from the internet because I don't usually code in Python but I am forced to in this case (I can't use Ruby's 'docx' module for various reasons). So `docx_replace_regex()` does exactly what it's name suggests: opens the *.docx* file, finds the text that needs to be replaced and replaces it with replace (even if the text that needs to be replaced is found in a table or another paragraph).

What I'm trying to do is basically pass a new name/label/tag (whatever you want to call it) as a parameter to the file and change the old name/label/tag from the *.docx* file with the parameter and save the newly edited *.docx* file to another new *.docx* file.

This code works fine if the name/tag/label I'm trying to replace does not have any dots. In fact, I tested it on other strings from tables and it worked just fine. Since this name/tag/label contains dots I had to use `re.compile(re.escape())` so the dots would not be considered special characters and I thought it should work, but for some reason after the new file is generated, nothing is changed.

I printed out `regex1` and `replace1` to see the values. `regex1` has the following format: `re.compile('tag\\.name\\.label')` while `replace1` is just *tag.name.label* without any `''` or `""`. I think that this might be the problem for the misbehaviour, but I'm not sure since I'm very new to Python.

Can anyone help me with this? Is there something I'm missing?